# Simple scala code: Returning first element from string array

Tags: scala

I don't know how to fix this code. It "explodes" somewhere in **returnFirstString** but I don't know why. Also, I don't know how to properly display result using **println**. Is this approach ok.

So here's the code:

```
def returnFirstString(a: Array[String]): Option[String]=
{
    if(a.isEmpty) { None }
    Some(a(0))
}
val emptyArrayOfStrings = Array.empty[String]
println(returnFirstString(emptyArrayOfStrings))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're not properly returning the None:

```
  def returnFirstString(a: Array[String]): Option[String] = {
    if (a.isEmpty) {
      None
    }
    else {
      Some(a(0))
    }
  }
```

Also, there's already a method for this on most scala collections:

```
emptyArrayOfStrings.headOption
```

Answer (score 5):

The most concise way:

```
def returnFirstString(a: Array[String]): Option[String]= a.headOption
```